# Email doesn't maintain formatting after sending VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, email, text, richtextbox, text-formatting

I am using EASendmail to send emails.The email body is a rich textbox.If i do formatting e.g. One line below another and send the email,the email loses it's formatting. For example if type this :

```
Hello,
How are you ?
```

in the rich text box and send it,then it becomes :

```
Hello,How are you
```

How do i maintain the text formatting ? And one more thing, if i add any image to my rich textbox, the email body doesn't keep the image ..I mean , the receiver only receives the texts of the email body, not the image. How to fix these issues ?

My code to send email is :

```
 Dim oMail As New SmtpMail("TryIt")
 Dim oSmtp As New EASendMail.SmtpClient()
 oMail.From = fromtxt.Text
 oMail.To = New AddressCollection(totxt.Text)
 oMail.Subject = subjecttxt.Text
 oMail.HtmlBody = bodytxt.Text
 Dim oServer As New SmtpServer(MailConfig.host.Text)
 oServer.Port = MailConfig.port.Text
 oServer.ConnectType = SmtpConnectType.ConnectSSLAuto
 oServer.User = fromtxt.Text
 oServer.Password = MailConfig.password.Text
 oSmtp.SendMail(oServer, oMail)
```

**EDIT**

I even tried :

```
  oMail.HtmlBody = "<html><body>" + bodytxt.Text + "</body></html>"
```

But no results

Comment: Have you tried to send the email with the body as HTML?

Comment: RichText is not the same as HTML.  You'll have to convert it somehow.  I'm not sure how to embed images - never tried that.

Comment: @DiscipleMichael, `oMail.HtmlBody = bodytxt.Text` ..Doesn't it send the rich text box as an html ?

Comment: Place a debug point when that text is assigned and use the text visualizer to see what it's actually assigning

Comment: sorry, i don't understand, can you explain ?

Comment: okey, got it,and please mark the answer as answer to help others

Comment: @zackraiyan you are supposed to do that yourself.

Comment: but i can't do that in 3 days(when i click on MARK AS ANSWER,it says i can't accept my own answer in 3 days)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an easy fix .
All i had to do is convert my RTF to HTML and then send it..[RTF-TO-HTML-CONVERTER](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27431/Writing-Your-Own-RTF-Converter)

After downloading the project files, reference must be added to the .dll files in the bin folder.Then :

```
  Imports Itenso.Rtf.Converter.Html
  Imports Itenso.Rtf.Support
  Imports Itenso.Rtf

   Dim rr As String = bodytxt.Rtf.Replace("\0", "")
    Dim rtfDocument As IRtfDocument = RtfInterpreterTool.BuildDoc(rr)
    Dim htmlConverter As New RtfHtmlConverter(rtfDocument)
    Dim html1 As String = htmlConverter.Convert()

    ' my other codes in-between(read my post)

     oMail.HtmlBody = html1
```